# Doctrine2 Iteration

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have the following code for a `<select>` on a form.

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT g.name, g.id FROM SSMURBS\Group g ORDER BY g.name ASC");`
$groups = $query->iterate();`
$groups_option = "";
foreach( $groups as $row ){
    $group = $row[0];
    $groups_option .= "<option val=\"{$group['id']}\">{$group['name']}</option>\n";
}
```

But this throws an error. What works is...

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT g.name, g.id FROM SSMURBS\Group g ORDER BY g.name ASC");
$groups = $query->iterate();

$groups_option = "";
$i = 0;
foreach( $groups as $row ){
    $group = $row[$i];
    $groups_option .= "<option val=\"{$group['id']}\">{$group['name']}</option>\n";
    $i++;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? The reference manual cites the first option as correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question:

While DQL permits `SELECT g.id, g.name` without throwing an error, this is actually SQL, not DQL. (Thanks, doctrine reference manual, for being so clear on this...)

The correct way to code this is

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT partial g.{id,name} FROM SSMURBS\Group g ORDER BY g.name ASC");
$groups = $query->iterate();

$groups_option = "";
foreach( $groups as $group ){
$group = $group[0];
$groups_option .= "<option value=\"{$group->id}\">{$group->name}</option>\n";
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your variable names are mismatched.

Remove `$group = $row[0]` and use `foreach ($groups as $group)`

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT g.name, g.id FROM SSMURBS\Group g ORDER BY g.name ASC");
$groups = $query->iterate();
$groups_option = "";
foreach ( $groups as $group ){
    $groups_option .= "<option val=\"{$group['id']}\">{$group['name']}</option>\n";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work: when you use `->iterate()` within foreach, the single variable (here `$group`) is always encapsulated in an array. If you try to do this it won't find your data.